# How to Set listbox location in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

i want to set listbox location. In Winform i did this by using this code   `listbox.Location` but in WPF there is no   `listbox.Location` property.

**Edit 1:**

```
 var rect = txtBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(txtBox.CaretIndex);

 var point = rect.BottomRight;

 lstBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

 //Want to achieved this
 //TextBox.Location = point;
```

I am creating something like Intellisense with listbox

Comment: Please add your code and instead of location, try using Margin property

Comment: you can not use the same principles of winforms.

Comment: I want to feed point values on Y Axis of listbox.

Comment: See my post below - Margin has four parts: Left, Top, Right, Bottom. You can feed to that. Left is like X, Top is like Y.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read up on WPF layouts, however to you can use the `ListBox.Margin` to position the `ListBox` in a hardcoded location.

```
listbox.Margin = new Thickness( 25, 200, 0, 0 );
```

or in XAML

```
<ListBox Margin="25,200,0,0"/>
```

Comment: i want to set point values on y axis on listbox. 
   In WinForm i did like this   `listbox.Location = p` Where p is   `p.Y += (int)rtbInput.Font.GetHeight()*2;`

Comment: WPF does not work in that way. It would prefer you to create a structured layout. When you create a layout like this, window resizing and other such features are handled pretty much for you.[Consider this simple tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html).

Answer (score 0):

A ListBox's location is determined relative to the control it is contained in. To set a location within it's parent control you can use the HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment and Margin Properties.

Here is an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
         <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="197,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note - all these properties are available programmatically as well.

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: I used This
   `var rect = txtBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(txtBox.CaretIndex);

    var point = rect.BottomRight;          

    lstBox1.Margin = new Thickness(0, point.Y, 0, 0);`
On textbox GotFocus Event but the problem is when textbox is focused   listbox just docked to the main windows

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what the parent panel is to determine how to set the position of your listbox. You'll need to read more about [Layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in WPF. Let's look at 2 panels to get you started, Grid and Canvas.

```
<Grid>
  <ListBox x:Name="lb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>

lb.Margin = new Thickness(10,10,0,0);
```

The example above sets the ListBox lb in the Grid at position (10,10).

```
<Canvas>
  <ListBox x:Name="lb"/>
</Canvas>

Canvas.SetTop(lb, 10);
Canvas.SetLeft(lb, 10);
```

The example above does the same for lb in a Canvas.

As you can see, it depends on what type of panel that you put your listbox into to be able to set the position correctly.